# How to retrieve data from multiple daily tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I need some help in retrieving data from multiple tables which have same columns with same datatype.

Currently I have multiple tables in my database, each table contains data for a single day. For example, I have the following tables:

- Table_20160820
- Table_20160821
- Table_20160822
- Table_20160823
- Table_20160824
- Table_20160825

All the tables have same columns with same datatype say:

- column_1
- column_2
- column_3
- column_4

Now, is it possible to retrieve the columns from all the tables using a single query.

What I am exactly looking for is to get the count of column_3 which will be grouped by column_1 for all the tables. I want to avoid writing multiple queries as I need to fetch the data for an entire month i.e. from 30 tables.

Comment: Different tables for different dates... Sounds like a bad idea. (Have one table, add a date column!)

Comment: Agree with @jarlh: this is a **horribly bad** design and will make your life as a database developer a *living hell* ! Fix the design - don't waste time trying to "optimize" access to this mess ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have said, it'd be best to organize this into a single table, and then add a date column so you can see when each row was added.  You can even set the default value of the `date_created` column to be `getdate()`.

To get all of the data together use the `UNION` Operator in conjunction with an insert statement to your new better table.

```
CREATE TABLE Better_Table (Column_1 <type>, Column_2 <type>, ..., Date_Created DateTime2(7) Default GETDATE())
GO
INSERT INTO Better_Table (Column_1, Column_2, ...)
SELECT *, '2016/08/22' FROM Table_20160822
UNION
SELECT *, '2016/08/23' FROM Table_20160823
...
```

Once you've done this your query will be far simpler:

```
SELECT Column_1, COUNT(Column_3)
FROM Better_Table
WHERE date_created >= '2016/08/01'
AND date_created < '2016/09/01'
GROUP BY Column_1
```

Although you can still do this in the db current state by using the union operator in the `group by` query.  It would look something like this:

```
SELECT a.column_1, COUNT(a.column_3)
FROM ( 
SELECT column_1, Column_3
FROM Table_20160822
UNION ALL
SELECT column_1, Column_3
FROM Table_20160823
) a
GROUP BY a.Column_1
```

Just expand this to the tables you need to grab from.

Comment: Hi as you have mentioned that it will be better to create a new table. I am trying to do by using the SELECT * INTO command. But for some reason it is not creating the new table with all the columns.

Comment: @Ajitav Ya you'll need to create the table before you can insert into it.  I've updated my answer to show how you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE to get all dates you need, then create a query and execute it:

```
DECLARE @dateStart datetime = '2016-08-01',
        @dateFinish datetime = '2016-09-01',
        @query nvarchar(max)

;WITH cte as (
SELECT  @dateStart as d
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(day,1,d)
FROM cte
WHERE DATEADD(day,1,d) < @dateFinish
)

SELECT @query = (

    SELECT 'SELECT column_1, COUNT(column_3) FROM ( '
    + STUFF((
    SELECT  ' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM [Table_'+CONVERT(nvarchar(8),d,112)+'] '
    FROM cte
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,10,'') + ') as t GROUP BY column_1 '
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

PRINT @query

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Output of `@query` variable:

```
SELECT column_1, COUNT(column_3) 
FROM (  
    SELECT * FROM [Table_20160801]  UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM [Table_20160802]  UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM [Table_20160803]  UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM [Table_20160804]  UNION ALL 
    ....
    SELECT * FROM [Table_20160831] 
) as t
GROUP BY column_1
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above this is a bad design and it would be good if the design is fixed at first place. This is a technical debt which has to be paid back sooner or later. Anyway here's how you can do it:

```
DECLARE @dtStartDate        DATE,
        @dtEndDate          DATE,
        @nvchTablePrefix    NVARCHAR(50),
        @nvchQuery          NVARCHAR(max)


SELECT  @dtStartDate = '20160801', 
        @dtEndDate = '20160831',
        @nvchTablePrefix = 'Table_'


CREATE TABLE #temp
(name NVARCHAR(100))

WHILE(@dtStartDate <= @dtEndDate)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT  ' SELECT column_1, column_3 FROM ' + @nvchTablePrefix +    CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@dtStartDate,112)

SELECT @dtStartDate = DATEADD(d,1,@dtStartDate)

IF (@dtStartDate <= @dtEndDate)
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT  ' UNION '
END



SELECT @nvchQuery = 'SELECT column_1, COUNT(column_3) as column3count FROM ( '

SELECT @nvchQuery = @nvchQuery + name FROM #temp

SELECT @nvchQuery = @nvchQuery + ') t GROUP BY column1'



PRINT @nvchQuery
EXEC sp_executesql @nvchQuery


DROP TABLE #temp
```

OUTPUT of print statement will be like -

```
 SELECT column_1, COUNT(column_3) as column3count 
 FROM 
 (   SELECT column_1, column_3 FROM Table_20160801 
     UNION  
     SELECT column_1, column_3 FROM Table_20160802 
     UNION  
     .... 
     UNION  
     SELECT column_1, column_3 FROM Table_20160831
 ) t GROUP BY column1
```